# How to add item to object parent popup menu in Blender >= 3.0

Tags: python, scripting, 3d-view, interface

I am able to add an operator to the `Object > Parent` menu in the `3D Viewport`, however; I would like to add the operator to the popup/context menu which comes up by pressing `Ctrl-P` in the `3D Viewport`.  My operator was added to `Object > Parent` using the following:

```
import bpy

...

def menu_draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    layout.separator()
    layout.operator('scene.item_fit', text='Object and fit to character')

...

def register():
    ...
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object_parent.append(menu_draw)

def unregister():
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object_parent.remove(menu_draw)
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    register()
```

While I cannot seem to locate the class which defines the popup menu, it seems that it is called using `object.parent_set` per `Edit > Preferences > Keymap > 3D View > Make Parent`.  In `./scripts/startup/bl_ui/space_view3d.py` under the `draw` method of the `VIEW3D_MT_object_parent` class, I see `object.parent_set` listed using `layout.operator_enum('object.parent_set', 'type')`.  That would be the `bl_idname` for the class, but in order to append my operator to the appropriate menu, I would need to know the actual class name.  I did try exploring `bpy.types.OBJECT_` and `bpy.types.VIEW3D_` for what might be the class, but this turned up empty.

I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: I think you want [VIEW3D_MT_object_parent](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/594f47ecd2d5367ca936cf6fc6ec8168c2b360d0/release/scripts/startup/bl_ui/space_view3d.py#L2615) so I'm not sure if there's a way to add it to the popup as well as the object menu.

Comment: @MartyFouts, `VIEW3D_MT_object_parent` is exactly how I was able to get it work in the `object` context menu.  While that is viable for now, it would be nice to add it to the popup as well.  If it comes down to it, I suppose I could write my own popup, calling the same operators plus my own and map that to `Ctrl-P` as a work-around.